# Updating node over apt causes npm downgrade

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources, nodejs, npm

Every time I upgrade node.js (to `14.17.2` today) using apt, it somehow downgrades npm (e.g. from `7.19.1` to `6.14.13`).
I have to manually upgrade npm using `npm install -g npm` every time. I've been doing this since npm version 7 came out and have experienced this issue on several machines (20.04, 18.04, Raspberry Pi OS x64, ...).

Node source file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal main
```

I've searched for similar issues on this network and on other sites, but found none.
Thanks for the help and information in advance!

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1218